# How to handle navigation if I have to capture data for all parent/child relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an object Foo with various attributes (*val1, val2, val3*)
Foo also has a collection of bars (through has_many relationship)

Bar has attributes (*val4, val5, val6*)
Bar also has a collection of keys (through has_many relationship)

Key has attributes (*val7*)

While I create a Foo object, I would like to create / modify all Bar objects. There is a provision to add a new Bar in the screen.
When a user is modifying a Bar, he might also add few Key(s).

But a Bar object cannot be created/saved without a Foo.
How should I handle this, is there a gem which abstracts this page flow and storage of objects. I would like to store all objects only when Foo is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement some :

- `after_create` in your `Foo` model, to create/modify its `bars`.
- `after_update` in your `Bar` model, to add `keys`.

Be careful with those functions, don't create some infinite loops.